# Where is .gtkrc on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk

I want to manually edit my color scheme, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
~/.themes/[your theme]/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

Comment: it could also be in /usr/share/themes/.....

Answer (score 2):

If you regularly update locatedb , you can use

```
locate .gtkrc
```

to locate files in Ubuntu

Comment: I just tried it, got 6 different results and none of them is my current theme

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of gtkrc files:

(1) "System-wide" theme files which reside in the location mentioned by hasen `/usr/share/themes/<your theme>/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

(2) Your own customizations, which are stored in ~/.gtkrc-2.0 (Note that the 2.0 is important)

Usually there is no need to edit the system-wide files, and user customizations should be in the home directory